# Перевод строчки `You can now`

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Переведите, пожалуйста, строчку `You can now`:

> [image: скриншот строки без перевода]

Она появляется в профиле при получении новой привилегии.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод добавлен:

> Теперь вы можете

Будет на сайте после подкачки transifex и пересборки движка.